# Rails 7 Encryption Email + Devise (ERROR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using Rails 7 + Devise gem. I'm trying to encrypt the email field (generated by devise). I successfully did rails db:encryption:init and set my credentials.

User Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  
  encrypts :email, deterministic: true, downcase: true
  validates :email, presence: true
  
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :confirmable

end
```

When I try to visit both sign in and sign up path, I get these errors:

```
ActiveRecord::Encryption::Errors::Decryption in Devise::Sessions#new

ActiveRecord::Encryption::Errors::Decryption in Devise::Registrations#new
```

Both point to this line in the view:

```
<%= f.input :email,
```

Even when I try to create a new user through the rails console, I get:

```
unexpected token at '' (JSON::ParserError) 
ActiveRecord::Encryption::Errors::Encoding (ActiveRecord::Encryption::Errors::Encoding)
ActiveRecord::Encryption::Errors::Decryption (ActiveRecord::Encryption::Errors::Decryption)
```

How can I solve this? Is the new Rails 7 ActiveRecord Encryption available with Devise?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this should help with your error https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/5436#issuecomment-1014152052

There are 2 approaches, you can set:

```rb
config.active_record.encryption.support_unencrypted_data = true
```

or change migration for email field:

```
null: false, default: ""
```

Answer (score 1):

Your need to remove the `default: ""` from users

```
class RemoveDefaultEmailFromUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def up
    change_column_default(:users, :email, nil)
  end

  def down
    change_column_default(:users, :email, '')
  end
end
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).